# Whether Selenium + JUnit is the best practice to test web application in the industry now?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, junit

I'm a beginner in the testing field. I know that Selenium is a best open source tool to display automatic web testing. But Selenium need an another tool to drive its test scripts. What I really want to know is whether combining Selenium with JUnit is the best practice to test web application in the industry now. If not, what is the best practice to display Selenium testing in the industry?

Answer (score 5):

If talking about web browser "simulators" then there are basically 2 most popular & most developed engines so far: **HtmlUnit** and **Selenium with it's drivers**.

**Selenium** actually launches specified browser and sends command to it directly which means that quality of simulation is very close to real one.

**HtmlUnit** instead only tries to simulate different browsers functionality without actually launching them, which means that quality of simulation is way worse.

From my experience,  **Selenium** with it's ChromeDriver was able to successfully load **heavy JS** page and do actions on it, while **HtmlUnit** failed even after several hours of tuning it with different configuration options.

Out of these points, I assume that Selenium is the best simulation engine so far.

Now, concerning testing frameworks: there are **JUnit** or **TestNG**. I don't want to start holy war, but IMO **JUnit** is better and more widespread and hence, is more actively developed.

So, yes, **Selenium** + **JUnit** is so far the best combination for testing web applications.

P.S. There are also **hybrid** solutions like **JWebUnit** which simply adds some useful `assertXXX()` methods to **JUnit** + **HtmlUnit**/**Selenium** combination, but anyway it's still **JUnit** + **Selenium** :)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain what's the difference between JUnit and TestNG. Which is better? I have learned Robot Framework these days. How about Robot Framework?

Comment: Concerning **JUnit 4 vs TestNG**: **JUnit** is *canonical* testing framework because it was around since 2000 i.e. long before **TestNG**. **TestNG** was released in 2004 and solved some issues which were missing in **JUnit** at that time. 

**But for now they are almost the same** except for some minor differences, so I would say it's **a matter of taste** and fact that **JUnit is more widespread**.

Comment: I've never worked with **Robot Framework** but from what I've just read it seems that for web testing it uses **Selenium** under the hood, so in the end of the day it is **Selenium** limited by **Robot Framework**'s interface (and from what I've seen it's quite limited compared to plain Java)

Answer (score 0):

BDD Good Mix is Selenium+Junit+JBehave
[you can check here](http://www.slideshare.net/shadrik/bdd-with-java-8323915)